# How to uninstall opencv in Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, opencv, uninstallation, ubuntu-12.04

I have the following system:

Linux 64 bit LTS 12.04

1. I have multiple installations of opencv library on the system.
2. I want to know the procedure to remove all opencv libraries from the system.
3. I am having trouble while executing my program through Eclipse IDE.

Though I can build the project when I try to execute it, it gives the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (k == STD_VECTOR_MAT) in release, file /build/buildd    /opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1364
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1364: error: (-215) k == STD_VECTOR_MAT in function release
```

Confusing thing is I am not able to find the path specified in the error i.e.

```
/build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp
```

I am able to compile the same source code using command line tool gcc and using pkg-config. 
However I am unable to do the same through eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 8):

You can also uninstall by going to the "build" folder directory of opencv from terminal, and execute the following

```
make uninstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r build
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/opencv2 /usr/local/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv2 /usr/local/share/opencv /usr/local/share/OpenCV /usr/share/opencv /usr/share/OpenCV /usr/local/bin/opencv* /usr/local/lib/libopencv*
```

Answer (score 5):

I remember I used this command a while ago to remove all opencv related things. It is interactive which promote you to remove the file. choose y or n depending.Take your time and be-careful

```
$> sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is `cd /path/to/cv/build` then `sudo make uninstall`. Of course you will have to have the source code with you

I tried the exec rm thing but nothing changed. Also FYI, `sudo apt-get remove libopencv-*` did not remove openCV for me

Comment: For me, @Damilola's answer, then `sudo apt-get remove libopencv-*`, and then @isrish's answer. Worked